# Redirecting output of nohup in docker not working

Tags: docker, nohup

I have to run a flask application in docker. The application is started when I run start.sh (details below) which started the application using nohup command and redirects the output to a logfile.

This is running fine in normal Linux system (without docker), but when I run this inside a docker container, the log file does not show any output. In the docker container, the log file is generated with size 0 and the log output is dumped in nohup.out file.

I am not sure why the output is redirected to nohup.out instead of the specified logfile, while it is working fine in my current Linux setup.

start.sh:

```
nohup uwsgi --ini /home/myuser/myapp/play.ini &>> /home/myuser/myapp/logs/play.nohup.out &
```

Dockerfile:

```
#Download base image ubuntu 16.04
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git-core
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get install -y python

# get application code and install python packages
RUN git clone <..git directory...> /home/myuser/myapp
RUN pip install -r /home/myuser/myapp/requirements.txt

# Setup nginx
RUN cp /home/myuser/myapp/myapp.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf

CMD sleep 600
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: share your dockerfile when you asking in context of docker, without dockerfile it hard to help.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue using cron commands, the issue I found is that the command was ran with shell, but **shell** does not support `&>>` as it is a **bash** feature.

I was able to overcome that using a command with the following synthax:

```
command >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

You could find more informtion on this link https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/

Answer (score 0):

You generally don’t use `nohup` in Docker at all.  Usually you want to set things up so that your container runs its main job *as a foreground process*.  (There’s not really much point in installing a bunch of stuff in an image, and then have it sit idle for 10 minutes and then exit.)

You should change the last line of your Dockerfile to

```
CMD uwsgi --ini /home/myuser/myapp/play.ini
```

If you `docker run` the resulting image without the `-d` flag, it will print its output to stdout; if you do use `-d`, you can retrieve it later using `docker logs`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree to this. But what if I have to start multiple applications on startup?

Comment: Canonically you’d run them in multiple separate containers.