# How to get docker commands to run in the background with nohup

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I'm running a docker command thus:

```
docker exec -t -i 44a1459f4468 cloudgene run imputationserver@1.4.1 --files /chrX_impute/ALL.chrX.Non.Pseudo.Auto.phase3_v5.shapeit2_mvncall_integrated.noSingleton.genotypes.vcf.gz --refpanel apps@1000g-phase-3-v5@2.0.0 --conf /etc/hadoop/conf --population mixed --mode qconly --output /chrX_impute/ALL.chrX.Non >  ALL.chrX.Non.qc.log 2>&1
```

using advice that I got from [Redirecting output of nohup in docker not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690850/redirecting-output-of-nohup-in-docker-not-working) and redirection

However, when I run this command, it does not run in the background.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268284/nohup-doesnt-work-as-expected-in-docker-script makes it sound as if adding `-t` will make it run as if it's a shell command, but that only works with docker `run`.

How can I get this docker command to run with nohup?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32387290/4281353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docker exec documentation page https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

```
--interactive , -i      Keep STDIN open even if not attached
--tty , -t              Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

I guess removing both the `-i` and `-t` flags would probably be sufficient